# Intellij: How can I wrap a piece of text in Javadoc?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, comments, keyboard-shortcuts, javadoc

So, for example, if I were to insert a Javadoc comment for a field from some external source on web, I would copy paste the relevant part from the website and then move on to my Class to incorporate the copied content as a Javadoc comment for the field.

But the problem is, I can't find any support from Intellij regarding this. Currently, I have to type, `/** + Enter` to generate a stub then paste the content there, which doesn't get properly pasted - I mean, a paragraph of 5 lines comes as a single long line and the Javadoc * on the side disappears.

I was looking for something like, paste the content copied raw in the place then select it and if Intellij provides some shortcut to wrap it as a Javadoc comment, do it except I couldn't find any support from Intellij for this approach.

So my question is, does anyone know of any such tool/plugin/built-in Intellij support or any other workaround for doing this as this is time consuming?

Comment: Can you paste it, highlight it, press `ctrl + /` to comment it, then add an extra star to the `/*`?

Comment: Ctrl + / generates single line(//...) comments and that too on the extreme left.

Comment: You could highlight the text full of `//`, replace `//` with `*` in selection, then modify the open and closing delimiters manually.

Comment: @byxor : That is also time consuming. Also, it doesn't create a professionall Javadoc. I just tried your suggestion - you can check for yourself.

Comment: What makes a javadoc comment professional besides its contents? I was giving a method to "wrap" whatever text you want in a comment

Comment: @byxor : The // get generated at the extreme left but the Javadoc comment should be indented properly. Also, your method is time consuming.

Comment: True. I'm unaware of a built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to start with the `/**` and <kbd>Return</kbd> to get the basic javadoc comment. Then you can paste your text with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on OSX) as the cursor is positioned at the right place.

All that is left then is use the keyboard shortcut that is defined for reformatting. In the menu you will find that under _Code/*Reformat Code*, on my Mac it is <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: unfortunatelly this doesn't work for multiline text